# React hook UseContext not returning correct value (according to typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code that receives the `dispatch` method:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: React.Dispatch<AppAction>) => ({

});
```

I use `useContext` like so;

```
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const [state, dispatch] = appContext;
```

When running `mapDispatchToProps(dispatch);` however I get the following error:

`Error:(28, 24) TS2345: Argument of type '[AppState, Dispatch<AppAction>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dispatch<AppAction>'.
  Type '[AppState, Dispatch<AppAction>]' provides no match for the signature '(value: AppAction): void'.`

It thinks `dispatch` is still an array… What's going on?

Comment: this is an ts issue - `useContext()` returns a method and you try to assign an array

Comment: Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to declare the type for your context as follows:

`export const AppContext = React.createContext<[AppState, Dispatch<AppAction>] | null>(null);`

Instead of `export const AppContext = React.createContext<Array<[AppState, Dispatch<AppAction>]> | null>(null);`